# how to know the weight of a image of gallery?

Tags: titanium-mobile, appcelerator

```
 Ti.Media.openPhotoGallery({
    success:function(event) {                   
 attch = event.media;       
    },
    cancel:function(){
        console.log("error!");
    }
});
```

How can I know the weight of attch? and if is possible, the name of file in gallery.

Comment: what is the library you are using ? Also have you tried event.media.width ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As is mentioned in the documenation, method `success` will return an object that contain property `media` which is image/video in Blob format. If you want to know width of an image do this:

```
Ti.Media.openPhotoGallery({
    success: function(event) {
        var image = event.media;

        console.log(image.width);
        console.log(image.size); // image size in bytes
    }
});
```

Comment: What? Weight? What value do you expect?